# How can i set a cookie for a standardController?

Tags: cookies

I'm doing a test class and i need to set a cookie for my page (ApexPages.StandardController).

I have to use something like: apexPages.currentPage().setCookies();

But, since i am simulating a page and not using a actual one, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Test.setCurrentPageReference to set up a "current page" context.

```
Test.setCurrentPageReference(Page.somePageName);
```